# How to make a message box time out?

Tags: vba, outlook

When I receive a message in Outlook from a certain group, containing a certain text, I have it run a script.

```
Sub AutoReply(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    msg = MsgBox("Would you like to reply to '" & Item.Subject & "' from '" & Item.SenderName & "'?", vbYesNo, "A Helpful Hand")
    If msg = vbYes Then
        GoTo SendEmail
    Else
        GoTo Die
    End If

SendEmail:
    Dim olkReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olkReply = Item.Reply
    With olkReply
        .To = "TestEmail@test.com"
        .Subject = "RE: " & Item.Subject
        .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:.0001pt;color:#1f497d;'>Auto Reply Test</p><p style='font-family:tahoma;font-size:15px;color:#17365d;margin-bottom:.0001pt;'>Test</p>" & olkReply.HTMLBody
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = Date + 0.07
        .Send
    End With
    Set olkReply = Nothing

Die:
    Set olkReply = Nothing
End Sub
```

When the message box pops up, I want it to go away after 10 seconds if no option is selected. I either want it to cancel or select the option vbNo (GoTo Die).

I updated, but it is throwing an error.

```
Sub AutoReplyTest(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Set objWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    intResult = objWSH.Popup("Would you like to reply to '" & Item.Subject & "' from '" & Item.SenderName & "'?", 10, "A Helpful Hand", vbYesNo)

Select Case intResult
Case 6:
    Dim olkReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olkReply = Item.Reply
    With olkReply
        .To = "Test@Test.com"
        .Subject = "RE: " & Item.Subject
        .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:.0001pt;color:#1f497d;'>Test</p><p style='font-family:tahoma;font-size:15px;color:#17365d;margin-bottom:.0001pt;'>Test</p>" & olkReply.HTMLBody
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = Date + 0.07
        .Send
    End With
    Set olkReply = Nothing

Case 7, -1:
    Set olkReply = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set objWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
intResult = objWSH.Popup("Here is my message", 10, "Here is My Title", vbYesNo)
```

This will show the message for 10 seconds (the second argument).  The possible results are:

```
-1 Timed Out    
1 OK button
2 Cancel button
3 Abort button
4 Retry button
5 Ignore button
6 Yes button
7 No button
```

Comment: It threw an error up when I tried editing it. I put the updated code above. Maybe you know why? I'm still working on it as well.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. I didn't have a End Select statement but even though it works the same, it still will not end after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If the window is presented for however many seconds and the user does absolutely nothing, it does "automatically" disappear.

Subsequently, in this situation the answer in variable "intresult" is -1 ... it is only another value if the user presses one of the keys e.g.

- presses the Yes button, then "intresult" = 6
- presses the No button then "intresult" = 7

Therefore, instead of stating `Case 7, -1:` instead just state `Case -1`.

When I used the code which I have adapted for my purpose, I did not need the colon either.